# Play Framework 2 JSON Reads, deserialization of one variable

Tags: json, deserialization, playframework-2.4

I'm using Play Framework 2.4 and I'm trying to do a basic JSON deserialization with [Reads](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) but I get an error. Here is the code:

```
case class Config(action: String)
```

and somewhere,

```
implicit val configReads: Reads[Config] = (
  (__ \ "action").read[String]
  )(Config.apply _)
```

I think the configReads is correctly formed but I get an IDE error on the "read" method call (symbol not defined), when I compile the code I get the following error:

```
Error:(30, 27) overloaded method value read with alternatives:
  (t: String)play.api.libs.json.Reads[String] <and>
  (implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[String])play.api.libs.json.Reads[String]
 cannot be applied to (String => wings.common.json.Config)
      (__ \ "action").read[String]
                          ^
```

but, if instead of trying to deserialize ONE argument I declare a class with TWO arguments in the constructor and I write the code to deserialize it, it works.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

**Edit:**

Digging in the depth of Google I found [this](http://www.codequora.com/questions/15042205/how-to-serialize-deserialize-case-classes-to-from-json-in-play-2-1) for Play 2.1.x but I'm using the Json library for Play 2.4.1 so this problem should not be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
implicit val configReads: Reads[Config] = (
  (__ \ "action").read[String]
  ) map Config.apply
```